# how to configure the property value parameter of quartz from database?

Tags: java, jboss, quartz-scheduler

in my project there is requirement to email triggering So i use quartz for this.
i configure the quartz through the annotation:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = { @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "cronTrigger", propertyValue ="0 30 10 * * ?") })
@ResourceAdapter("quartz-ra.rar")
public class QuartzMDBTest implements Job {

  public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {


    System.out.println("Quartz1 job executed!");  
}
```

In above  code i set time 10:30 but i want to its come from database. how do achieve this?
propertyvalue only take constant expression.
please help me 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve it using annotaitons. Try to configure the quartz job using the code and not annotation. Here is a sample code for that:

```
    CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger();
    trigger.setName("dummyTriggerName");
    // fetch the value from DB here and create the CRON string accordingly
    final String cronString = "0 " + value fetched from DB + " 10 * * ?"
    trigger.setCronExpression(cronString );


Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```